# Google location autocomplete show only street number on select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-location-services

I'm using [vsGoogleAutoComplete](https://github.com/vskosp/vsGoogleAutocomplete)for my angular application. This library works perfectly and it shows suggestion when I start typing.

[image]

What it currently does is if I select the matched address it places the complete address in the **Enter Street name** field like following:

[image]
But I was wanting when I select the matched address Only street name & number will be in the input field and others will be in the corresponding fields.
I tried different ways but was unsuccessful. I feel like there is some easy way I couldn't find. Any help will be appreciated.

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oib1YweHin43SS3sZD3U?p=preview)**

```
<div class="form-group">

      <!--5217 98th St-->
      <label style="margin-top:50px;">Enter street name</label> 
      <input vs-google-autocomplete

             ng-model="address.name"
             vs-place="address.place" 
             vs-place-id="address.components.placeId"
             vs-street-number="address.components.streetNumber" 
             vs-street="address.components.street"
             vs-city="address.components.city"
             vs-state="address.components.state"
             vs-country-short="address.components.countryCode"
             vs-country="address.components.country"
             vs-post-code="address.components.postCode"
             vs-latitude="address.components.location.lat"
             vs-longitude="address.components.location.long"

             type="text" 
             name="address"
             id="address"
             class="form-control" 
             placeholder="Enter street name">



 <span class="help-block"><b>City: </b>{{address.components.city}}</span>
      <span class="help-block"><b>State: </b>{{address.components.state}}</span>
      <span class="help-block"><b>Country code: </b>{{address.components.countryCode}}</span>
      <span class="help-block"><b>Country: </b>{{address.components.country}}</span>
      <span class="help-block"><b>Postcode: </b>{{address.components.postCode}}</span>
      <span class="help-block"><b>Latitude: </b>{{address.components.location.lat}}</span>
      <span class="help-block"><b>Longitude: </b>{{address.components.location.long}}</span>
    </div>
```